# NGINX password protection for everything, but a single endpoint

Tags: nginx

I have two EC2 instances on AWS. I'm using NGINX 1.6 for both. The two instances are connected to an AWS load balancer. In order for the instances to be considered "up and running" the load balanced sends an HTTP request to both servers expecting a 200 result (OK).

Now, I would like to password protect the web access for both instances. For that I used these in the NGINX configuration:

```
 auth_basic "Restricted";
 auth_basic_user_file /var/www/mywebapp/public/.htpasswd
```

The issue is that there's no way to tell AWS of the credentials and once you enable the password protection, both instances are almost immediately considered `outOfService` and are not addressed anymore.

I would like to define an endpoint in the NGINX configuration, say `/heartbeat` that'll serve a file, say `itsok.html` file on my public folder, without the need for the credential check, while keeping the password protection for all other endpoints of my web app.

so far all my attempts to do so failed. How do I achieve that?

Here's my current NGINX configuration file:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {

        # Useful logs for debug.
        access_log      /var/www/laravel/access.log;
        error_log       /var/www/laravel/error.log;
        rewrite_log     on;

        listen   80;
        server_name mywebapp.com;

        root "/var/www/mywebapp/public";
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
              root /var/www/mywebapp/public;
        }

       auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/mywebapp/public/.htpasswd;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this location, or something similar. I haven't tried this but it seems fairly trivial. Have a file in the specified directory that the load balancer requests.

```
location /heartbeat {
  root /var/www/whatever/;
  auth_basic off;
}
```

You could alternately define a single PHP file which would probably be more useful, as it would show the whole stack is up. That could be something like this, but it would rely on that PHP file being there. It could output "success" or "fail" based on hitting a database, or anything else you wanted to do.

```
location = load-balancer-test.php {
  auth_basic off; # This is the only new bit
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

If it doesn't work you should play with it as the idea is probably about right. If all else fails post access / error logs when you try this and describe the behavior.